# Exporting project to Git in Eclipse vs IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, git, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am new to Git and was exploring the Git integration in Eclipse, IntelliJ, and Pycharm. In Eclipse, the way projects get exported seems to be that the project gets added to an existing repo, while in IntelliJ and PyCharm, the project's root directory itself becomes a Git repo. This approach made the most sense to me, but then again I don't have much experience in sharing code. This latter approach is also possible in Eclipse by clicking the "Use or create repository in parent folder of project" checkbox, but when I did so, Eclipse told me that using the parent folder was not recommended.

Now for my question: Why does Eclipse warn against doing precisely what JetBrains IDE's do by default? What are the dangers in using a project's parent folder as a Git repo?

I read online that it has to do with the fact that once the parent folder is created as a repo, you can't add any new projects to the repo. But what are the benefits of adding projects to existing repos vs just making a separate repo for each project to keep everything separate?